# comment_notes_before not working

Tags: comments, comment-form

In my code, `comment_notes_before` doesn't show anything.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'class_form'      => 'add_review',
    'label_submit'      => __( 'Leave a review' ),
    'comment_notes_before' => 'Before',
    'comment_field' =>  '<textarea id="review_text" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your review"></textarea>',
    'comment_notes_after'  => 'After>',
    'logged_in_as' => ''
);
comment_form($args);
```

Is there a problem in my code?

Comment: Did you check when you're logged out?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in

Comment: This is only displayed if you're logged out.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @birgire, the comment_notes_before argument is only shown to users who are not logged in. If you look at the [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/), there is an if construct that checks if a user is logged in. If they are logged in, then a filter and an action fired. If not, then the comment_notes_before text is echoed.

If you want to show the before text to users logged in, you can use one of those hooks and echo the before content.

```
<?php
$before = 'Before';

//* Show $before only to logged in users
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'wpse_106269_logged_in', 10, 2 );
function wpse_106269_logged_in( $commenter, $user_identity ) {
  echo $before;
}

$args = array(
  'class_form'      => 'add_review',
  'label_submit'      => __( 'Leave a review' ),
  'comment_notes_before' => $before, //* Only shows for logged out users
  'comment_field' => 
    '<textarea id="review_text" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your review"></textarea>',
  'comment_notes_after'  => 'After',
  'logged_in_as' => ''
);
comment_form($args);
```